# npm: module.js:457 throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog' on a mac using brew

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

I made the mistake (?) of following [the instructions on the npm getting started page](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node) and ran

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

Now, no matter what I do, any execution of npm results in this error, whether I run it as sudo or not.  Uninstalling and reinstalling node has not helped.

```
$ sudo npm

module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

I am on a mac and installed node using homebrew.

Comment: When uninstalling, you probably want to delete these too `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` (I'm guessing they got the wrong permissions).

Comment: That solved it.  --Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

[Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara)'s comment helped me solve this.  The solution:

Run 
    `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node`
to forcefully uninstall node even if there are other modules that require node.

Once this is completed, run 
    `brew uninstall --force node`
to remove all the versions of node on your machine, if there is more than one version running.

At last run the following commands to remove all files and install node again:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
rm /usr/local/bin/npm
brew install node
```

Comment: @Dave no luck with your suggestion too. Any other things you want us to try?

Comment: @learnningprogramming, you need to provide some information about what your situation is and what you have already tried so far.  Are you on OSX, and using homebrew?  When you say "no luck with your suggestion too" - what else have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In your Linux box;

You may need to add the following link

1. Go to NPM installtion dir << cd ~/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/>>
   (I'm using NODE Current LTS 6.9.2)
2. look for the file npm-cli.js in lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
   (File name can be cli.js or npm-cli.js)
3. cd ~/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin
4. mv npm npm_old
5. Crate a soft link in ~/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/bin
   ln -s PATH-TO/npm-cli.js npm

Try npm -v

**Optional**
if you need to update npm version pls do 
npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: npm-cli.js can be found here node-v6.9.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

Comment: The original question refers to OSX, not Linux.